Контейнер Docker через консоль
Доброй ночи! Попытался запустить контейнер через консоль командой
# docker run -p 7171:8080 -v /Users/kitka/Docker:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat:9

Все отлично, только вот в самом докере меня ждала такая картина:

Почему-то каждый раз создается много контейнеров, и непонятно зачем. По итогу нужный в самом низу, а выше контейнеры непонятно по какому принципу инициализировались.
Подскажите мою возможную ошибку, пожалуйста.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

В документации вполне понятно написано по какому — run каждый раз создаёт новый контейнер
